# 9-player Advanced Civilization rules

Tags: house-rules, advanced-civilization

We're playing our yearly Advanced Civilization game this Saturday, and we may have 9 people.  Does anyone have any 9-player rules?

We have all the extension maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't know any, you can easily figure it out and try if that works.

Official rules state:

```
pla  pan  tok
9    -   
8    4/5  47
7    4/5  55
6    4    55
5    3w   47
4    2e+  55
3    2w-  47
```

(players, panels, tokens)

I find it odd it allows 7 and 8 players to play with either 4 or 5 panels without varying the amount of token to use. I read it "you *must* use it, but we have to provide rules to allow you to play even if you don't have it".

Assumed that, there are two ways to amend it.

---

```
pla  pan  tok
9    6    55
8    5    47
7    5    55
6    4    55
```

the more **conservative approach** is to just assume they meant the western extra panel to be used and keep the tokens as they were. Problem is you would need a sixth panel to add a ninth player, and it doesn't officially exist (nor unofficially, AFAIK). If you take this route, you'll automatically also get a 10-player version, using 6 panels and 47 tokens.

---

```
pla  pan  tok
9    5    47
8    5    55
7    4    47
6    4    55
```

the **optimistic approach** assumes they messed up the token amounts trying to allow 7 and 8-player games to work both with 4 and 5 panels, so you fix it as in this table.

---

They would both need testing; before actually testing them in the field, actually counting territories and population in each panel could help (I didn't, yet).

Comment: Btw, what does the image at http://lohoris.net/:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/8oTDn.gif mean?

Comment: @Pacerier it's a visit counter, they were very common in the web 1.0 days, and I grow fond of it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Civ Expansion Project](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/79843/civilization-expansion-project).  Allows up to 18 players!

Answer (score 1):

Our group plays regularly with 9 players.  We add a Hittite empire using the orange Asia tokens starting in the small 1'er space in the middle east (Jerusalem?).  This empire uses the Asia AST and has a "start location" for barbarian hordes of the two large 1'er spaces of the Arabian desert.